# Al seleccionar un item en un ListView UWP se selecciona otro item totalmente al azar

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, binding, usercontrol

Tengo un ListView que muestra los datos de los clientes usando un UserControl. Dentro de ese UserControl tengo un CheckBox que utilizo para seleccionar los clientes. Enlazo ese CheckBox con la propiedad IsSelected de los clientes. Hasta ahí todo bien, cuando presiono el botón mostrar todos los clientes seleccionados me los muestra sin problema. El problema esta en que los item seleccionados en la lista se muestran de manera inesperada. Si selecciono un item en un lado de la lista, en el otro lado de la lista se selecciona otro item al azar, lo que provoca que los items no se seleccionen correctamente.

Por ejemplo si selecciono el item #1 también se selecciona el item #17 y si selecciono el item #20 también se selecciona el item #5 y así sucesivamente. A pesar de esto, los clientes se seleccionan correctamente, al hacer click en mostrar los cliente seleccionado estos se muestran correctamente, solo se muestran los clientes que yo seleccione explicitamente y no los que se seleccionaron al azar.

Hasta ahora he investigado en Internet pero no he podido encontrar una respuesta a mi problema. Solo pude encontrar un problema similar al mio en GitHub: https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-checkbox/issues/53

También he pensado utilizar la selección múltiple que implementa la lista `SelectionMode="Multiple"` pero no he encontrado la manera de escuchar en el UserControl cuando un item es seleccionado. Necesito saber cuando un item es seleccionado para poder cambiar el color de fondo de mi UserControl.

Y también he pensado en deshabilitar la virtualización de la lista pero no se si eso sea una buena idea.

Aquí le dejo el código que estoy utilizando.

#### ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="Lista" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Clientes, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle1}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Cliente">
            <local:ClienteUserControl x:Name="ClienteUserControl" 
                                      Cliente="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

#### UserControl XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MangoUWP.ClienteUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="using:Mango.Model"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    IsTabStop="True"
    UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">

    <Grid Width="272" Height="672">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="ItemIsSelected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="Card.Background" Value="{StaticResource AzulBlanquesino}"/>
                        <Setter Target="Card.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Azul}"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ItemIsNotSelected"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid x:Name="Card" BorderBrush="#d9d9d9" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">

            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                      Padding="0" MinWidth="0" Margin="0, 0, 8, 0"
                      IsChecked="{x:Bind Cliente.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Click="CheckBox_Checked">
            </CheckBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### UserControl C Sharp

```
public sealed partial class ClienteUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClienteProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Cliente",
        typeof(Cliente),
        typeof(ClienteUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Cliente Cliente
    {
        get { return (Cliente) GetValue(ClienteProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(ClienteProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ClienteUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cliente.IsSelected)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ItemIsSelected", true);
        } else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ItemIsNotSelected", true);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Cliente

```
public class Cliente: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private bool isSelected { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```